# Force sleuth to ignore incoming tracing headers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

Our system comprises of microservices that can accept requests from external sources but also can call our other internal microservices and some external microservices. Let's say they all communicate by http/rest.
How do I prevent external systems from poisoning my service with their own trace ids? It seems like a basic functionality, but I can't find an answer. I tried using the skip-pattern functionality, but it's for exporting spans and not for "restarting" the trace.

Edit:
I tried adding servlet filter to remove the header before it's processed, but the span is extracted inside the TraceValve - a part of Tomcat instrumetation and not part of standard filter chain.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ResetTraceFilter extends HttpFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilter(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain
    ) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        chain.doFilter(
            new RemoveHeaderHttpServletRequestWrapper("b3", request),
            response
        );
    }
}
```

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@Slf4j
public class SleuthAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<ResetTraceFilter> loggingFilter() {

        var registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<ResetTraceFilter>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new ResetTraceFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/*");
        registrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

I verified in the debugger that they are indeed run in the chain.

Train version: 2021.0.4
Spring Boot version: 2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Just create an Mvc Filter that will remove request headers before they get parsed by the Sleuth's filters.

Comment: I tried doing that (added request wrapper and used filter to wrap the request) but the span extractor is run from TraceVale inside Tomcat instrumentation code of Spring and not inside the filter chain, so the filter is called too late

Comment: Good point, so do the same at the Valve level